# Golang convert integer to unicode character

Tags: string, go, unicode

Given the following input:

```
intVal := 2612
strVal := "2612"
```

What is a mechanism for mapping to the associated unicode value as a string.

For example, the following code prints "☒"

```
fmt.Println("\u2612")
```

But the following does not work:

```
fmt.Println("\\u" + strVal)
```

I researched runes, `strconv`, and `unicode/utf8` but was unable to find a suitable conversion strategy.

Answer (score 5):

`2612` is not the integer value of the unicode rune, the integer value of `\u2612` is `9746`. The string `"2612"` is the hex value of the rune, so parse it as a hex number and convert it to a `rune`.

```
i, err := strconv.ParseInt(strVal, 16, 32)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
r := rune(i)
fmt.Println(string(r))
```

https://play.golang.org/p/t_e6AfbKQq

Comment: I'd note that `strconv.ParseInt()` returns a value of type `uint64` no matter which bit size was specified so in a less toy example one would probably need to type-convert the result to `rune`.

Comment: @kostix: good point, that happens implicitly in the string conversion.

Answer (score 3):

This one works:

```
fmt.Println("\u2612")
```

Because an [interpreted string literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals) is specified in the source code, and the compiler will unquote (interpret) it. It is **not** the [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) package that processes this unquoting.

This doesn't work:

```
fmt.Println("\\u" + strVal)
```

Because again an interpreted string literal is used which will be resolved to a `string` value `\u`, and then it will be concatenated with the value of the local variable `strVal` which is `2612`, so the final `string` value will be `\u2612`. But this is not an interpreted string literal, this is the "final" result. This won't be processed / unquoted further.

Alternatively to JimB's answer, you may also use [`strconv.Unquote()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Unquote) which does an unquoting similar to what the compiler does.

See this example:

```
// The original that works:
s := "\u2612"
fmt.Println(s, []byte(s))

// Using strconv.Unquote():
strVal := "2612"
s2, err := strconv.Unquote(`"\u` + strVal + `"`)
fmt.Println(s2, []byte(s2), err)
fmt.Println(s == s2)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/P13LRCMJPz)):

```
☒ [226 152 146]
☒ [226 152 146] <nil>
true
```

Something to note here: We want to unquote the `\u2612` text by `strconv.Unquote()`, but `Unquote()` requires that the string to be unquoted to be in quotes (*"Unquote interprets s as a single-quoted, double-quoted, or backquoted Go string literal..."*), that's why we pre- and postpended it with a quotation mark.