# Go - Is it possible to convert a raw string literal to an interpreted string literal?

Tags: string, go, ansi-escape

Is it possible to convert raw string literals to interpreted string literals in Go? (See [language specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals))

I have a raw string literal, but I want to print out to the console what one would get with an interpreted string literal—that is, text output formatted using escape sequences.

For example, printing this raw string literal gives

```golang
s := `\033[1mString in bold.\033[0m`
println(s) // \033[1mString in bold.\033[0m
```

but I want the same result one would get with

```golang
s := "\033[1mString in bold.\033[0m"
println(s) // String in bold. (In bold)
```

For context, I am trying to print the contents of a text file that is formatted with escape sequences using

```golang
f, _ := := ioutil.ReadFile("file.txt")
println(string(f))
```

but the output is in the former way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`strconv.Unquote()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Unquote):

```
s := `\033[1mString in bold.\033[0m`

s2, err := strconv.Unquote(`"` + s + `"`)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println("normal", s2)
```

This will output:

> normal **String in bold.**

Note that the `string` value passed to `strconv.Unquote()` must contain wrapping double quotes or backticks, and since the source `s` does not contain the wrapping quotes, I pre- and suffixed those like this:

```
`"` + s + `"`
```

See related questions:

[How do I make raw unicode encoded content readable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42365902/how-do-i-make-raw-unicode-encoded-content-readable/42366249#42366249)

[Golang convert integer to unicode character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43094132/golang-convert-integer-to-unicode-character/43096043#43096043)

[How to transform Go string literal code to its value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49303559/how-to-transform-go-string-literal-code-to-its-value/49304209#49304209)

[How to convert escape characters in HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36528575/how-to-convert-escape-characters-in-html-tags/36529158#36529158)

Comment: Thank you, @icza. Would you know why it doesn't work for the latter case where the string is read from a file with the same contents?

Comment: @TshakaEricLekholoane I'd guess because it's not the same content. Print the file content as bytes, also print `[]byte(s)`, and compare them byte-by-byte.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you not have raw string you need to write it as raw string and without changes thing like "\n" and others,and incase you want to return bytes:

```
s := "\033[1mString in bold.\033[0m"
rune := string([]rune(s))
b := []byte(rune)
f, err := os.OpenFile("filename.txt", os.O_RDWR, 0644)
if err != nil {
return err
}
if _, err := f.Write(b); err != nil {
    return err
}
```

with this approach, the bytes don't change so that the sh265 will be the same, and you return it after reading it from the file with no further changes.

second, for reading the data and printing:

```
bytes, err := os.ReadFile("filename.txt")
if err != nil {
  return err
}
s = strconv.Quote(string(bytes))
fmt.Println(s)
```

and you gone got "\x1b[1mString in bold.\x1b[0m"

Comment: I could not understand where is the data coming from since according to the question the data is read from a .txt file.  Please post a more detailed answer.

Comment: @NicholasFernandesPaolillo, you are right. I was in a hurry, but I am sure this answer is better, so I want to share it. I improved my answer

Comment: @NicholasFernandesPaolillo You taught me how to answer people's questions in StackOverflow; thanks to that, I edited and improved my answer event more.

Comment: Remember to not take it personally, your way of reading throw bytes is good, I have learned from it and used it in my work already, made an upvote for your question. Best regards.